# TypeError: res.end is not a function on express when I use nginx reverse proxy

Tags: express, nginx, pm2

On my server I have nginx and pm2 running side by side.

To make this work I configure my nginx to reverse proxy to my API (PM2)

```
# Proxying API connections to api
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
}
```

But when My UI call my API I receive this error..

> api > TypeError: res.end is not a function
>       api >     at onError (/var/www/api/source/api/api.js:75:9)
>       api >     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/api/source/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       api >     at trim_prefix (/var/www/api/source/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)

And when I check my code on line 75...

```
app.use(function onError (err, req, res) {
  res.statusCode = 500
  res.end(res.sentry + '\n') // Line 75
})
```

What's I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with nginx, do you modify the response object at any point before reaching that server error handler?

Comment: We will need to see more code to understand what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Error middleware should have 4 parameters, in this order:

```
app.use(function onError(req, res, next, err){
    //handle error
})
```

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)